# Update quantity in MongoDB based on 2 conditions in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm making a shopping cart in MongoDB and I want to update the quantity field if the user adds a product that's already added.

This is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : "mzipdNS2Xyw-IqV085KrBe5RZucp9M_KqDSYjPinq20",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "productId" : "27122",
            "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
            "displayPrice" : "€ 599.00",
            "price" : NumberLong(599),
            "name" : "APPLE IPHONE 5S 16GB SPACE GRAY"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm running the following code to update my document, but it's not working, can anyone assist me?

```
$collection->update(array("_id" => $userId, array("products" => array("productId" => $productId))),
                array('$set' => array("quantity" => $newQuantity
                ))
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the correct item in the products array you'll have to use the [positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

```
$collection->update(
    array(
        "_id" => $userId,
        "products.productId" => $productId,
    ),
    array('$set' => array("products.$.quantity" => $newQuantity))
);
```